# MySQL Workbench: Insert rows after checking data in 2 rows, loop on whole table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a local MySQL Server instance and the MySQL Workbench for university topics.

Following table apjournal contains start and endtimes at workstations.

- PAID is the production order,
- ID the running number when the starttime was scanned

[image: table apjournal]

I would like to insert rows for the transportation/buffer time after each workstation.

Conditions:

```
(r1 := row i, r2 := row i+1)

WHERE PAID_from_r1 = PAID _from_r1 AND ID_from_r2 > ID_from_r1

THEN 
INSERT INTO sys.apjournal (ID, PAID, RID, APID, APID_ST, Startzeit, Endzeit, DurationEvent) 
VALUES (0, PAID_from_r1, RID_from_r1, APID_from_r1, CONCAT('Puffer ',APID_from_r1), Endzeit_from r1, Startzeit_from_r2, 0);
```

I searched for While Loop and procedures and Subqueries with running nummers. Here are my tries.

```
SELECT
    -
    @ID := CASE
        WHEN @last_ID > data.actual_ID AND @last_PAID = data.acutal_PAID
        THEN @ID + 1            
        ELSE 0
    END AS ID,
    @last_ID := data.ID,
    @last_PAID := data.PAID
    #INSERT INTO sys.apjournal (ID, PAID, RID, APID, APID_ST, Startzeit, Endzeit, DurationEvent) VALUES (3000+i, 1, 1)
    -- //TODO: Weitere Felder ausgeben
FROM
    -- Die Variablen initialisieren
    (SELECT @nr:= 0, @last_ID:=1,@last_PAID:=76) AS vars,
    -- Die Daten sortieren
    (
        SELECT t.*
        FROM sys.apjournal AS t
        ORDER BY PAID
    ) AS data;
    
    
#other strategy ?

drop procedure if exists addPuffer;

DELIMITER //  

CREATE PROCEDURE addPuffer(
StartID INT,
PAID Int
)   
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0; 
WHILE (i<2000)  DO
    INSERT INTO sys.apjournal (ID, PAID, RID, APID, APID_ST, Startzeit, Endzeit, DurationEvent) VALUES (3000+i, 1, 1);
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END;
//  
CALL addPuffer();
```

The problems of structuring the procedures, matching 2 rows are new for me. The procedure should loop over the whole table.

Comment: *(r1 := row i, r2 := row i+1)* "row i" - this is a row where ID=i ?

Comment: Hi, no the ID is not i as a running number of rows.

Comment: So what is "i"?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and show us what the data set would look like before and after the operation. Omit extraneous information.

Comment: I think i need a running number? Don't be confused by the presented code. Maybe it goes into wrong direction.

Comment: Please answer MY question, not YOUR question. You tell that rows have some attribute `i` (in "row i") which can be incremented (as in "row i+1"). Define STRICTLY what column contains this `i` value or what expression may be used for to obtain its value.

Comment: @Akina: there is no column which contains i. "row i" should only show the row I meant in a loop.

Comment: You set some rows order and enumerate rows using this ordering, then use this enumeration as `i` mentioned above, is it? If so then define precisely this ORDER BY expression (remember - it must provide rows uniqueness for the result to be deterministic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the task can be solved with one query similar to

```
INSERT INTO sys.apjournal (ID, PAID, RID, APID, APID_ST, Startzeit, Endzeit, DurationEvent) 
SELECT /* DISTINCT */ 0, t1.PAID, t1.RID, t1.APID, CONCAT('Puffer ', t1.APID), t1.Endzeit, t2.Startzeit, 0
FROM apjournal t1
JOIN apjournal t2 ON t1.PAID = t2.PAID 
                 AND t1.ID < t2.ID
             /*  AND another joining conditions */
/* WHERE one more conditions */
```

But current question text does not allow to define what additional joining and filtering conditions needed.

Comment: One Problem is left. The Insert INTO does it twice, when there a for expample 2 workstation behind. How can I add sth. that it does the Insert into only one time per APID ? see the picture in your answer.

Comment: AND t1.ID < t2.ID : Here t2.Id should be the next bigger one. but Limit 1 ore DESC LIMIT 1 don't work.

Comment: AND t1.ID < t2.ID ORDER by PAID DESC Limit 1; doesn't work

Comment: I did it now with an help table with sequence order not depending on the APID:          JOIN sys.apjournal t2 ON t1.PAID = t2.PAID 
     AND t1.ap_sequence +1 = t2.ap_sequence;